# Затухание на css

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать затухание переход к белому фону для картинки или текста.

Но не пойму как избавиться от линии справа где резкий переход происходит. Слева плавно.

Или другие способы есть?

```css
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .box {
    position: relative;
  }

  .box:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 70%;
    left: 0%;
    box-shadow: inset -100px 0px 150px #fff;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <img src="http://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может надо использовать [gradient](http://htmlbook.ru/css3-na-primerakh/lineinyi-gradient)?

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 70%;
  left: 0%;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)', endColorstr='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)', GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно растянуть на всю ширину:

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .box {
    position: relative;
  }

  .box:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    box-shadow: inset -100px 0px 150px #fff;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <img src="http://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```